# C2998 cannot be a template definition error

Tags: c++11, templates

I met a couple of C2998 error recently, here is the first one:

Case 1, I can do

```
template <typename T> struct X { static char value; };
template <> char X<int>::value = 'a';
char X<char>::value = 'b';
```

, that when defining a static member of a fully specified template class, I can use either `template <>` or omitted it, though I don't know why both work.

Case 2 also compile:

```
template <typename T> struct X2{};
template <> struct X2<int> { static char value; };
char X2<int>::value = 'a';
```

, that when defining a static member of a fully specified template class, and the static member is not in the unspecified template, with `template <>` omitted, it compiles.

Case 3, if I add `template <>` back, this will trigger a C2998 error on the 2nd line:

```
template <> struct X2<char> { static char value; };
template <> char X2<char>::value = 'b';
```

why is it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes there's is difference, but i'd like to know *why* - by which law of C++ language the 3rd options does not work?

Comment: This is an unreadable mess. I think we can read the absence of `template<>` without the "help", thank you very much. Now, the third line in your case 1 is a compiler bug.

Comment: updated as normal format.

Comment: Contrary to your assertion, [Case 1 does not in fact compile](http://rextester.com/MOHW55012)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik in my Visual Studio 2013 it compiles.

Comment: What happens when you make instantations of all those templates with VS2013?